# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre usar la etiqueta video o un servidor de Streaming?

Tags: html

Estoy estudiando desarrollo web y no saben decirme mis profesores
que es mejor o que diferencias hay ya que html5, con la etiqueta video
puedes insertar preload etc etc como atributos. Según ellos, con la etiqueta
video, el navegador lo que hace es descargar el video y luego reproducirlo y con el streaming, lo va cargando poco a poco. Lo que les pregunte es que para 
que tiene el atributo preload la etiqueta video si lo que hace es descargarlo 
completo antes de verlo...
Me gustaria que me comentaseis el funcionamiento de la  y de un servidor de Streaming y compararlos.

PD: He montado un servidor de Streaming para una practica y la etqueta video
se usa para reproducir el video a través del protocolo rtmp:// pero me gustaría saber más.

Gracias ante todo.

Answer (score 0):

**Tag `<video>`**

Con el `preload` tienes 3 posibles atributos:

```
<video preload="auto|metadata|none">
```

> - auto = El video es descargado completamente cuando la pagina carga
> - metadata = Solo la metadata del vídeo es descargada cuando la pagina carga
> - none = El video no se descarga cuando carga la pagina, sino cuando se pulsa "play"

---

**Streaming:**

La carga de los vídeos se realiza a demanda, el servidor comprime los datos y envía, a medida que se va reproduciendo.